# Sqlite check if comma-separated numbers String contains a number

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, csv

How to check if a String in Sqlite contains a number? The string is comma-separated positive numbers not starting with 0. I need to check if it contains some other number?

Ex

- Is `5` in `1,2,1` -> No
- Is `5` in `35, 55, 15` -> No
- Is `5` in `5` -> Yes
- Is `5` in `0,5,1` -> Yes

P.S
*The comma-separated numbers are Android MMS Api, not something I got control of.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using string functions:

```
',' || mycsv || ',' like '%,' || myval || ',%' as found
```

`mycsv` represents your comma-separated string, and `myval` is the value you are looking for.

This returns a `0` / `1` value that indicates whether the value exists in the CSV string. You can use that in the `where` clause of a query of you like.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2e1f0a690a098bb8f420b161dc7b9f3f)**:

```
with t as (
    select '1,2,1' as mycsv, 5 as myval
    union all select '35,55,15', 5
    union all select '5', 5
    union all select '0,5,1', 5
)
select t.*, ',' || mycsv || ',' like '%,' || myval || ',%' as found
from t
```

```
mycsv    | myval | found
:------- | ----: | ----:
1,2,1    |     5 |     0
35,55,15 |     5 |     0
5        |     5 |     1
0,5,1    |     5 |     1
```